# Images Not Displaying on HTML Index Page, but Show up on All Other Pages

Tags: html, image, apache

I have quite the conundrum. Background- I have a webpage I made for fun as an easter egg for an internal site on my company's network. The index page isn't rendering the images and it's giving off a 404 not found error, even though I've triple checked and they're in the appropriate directory and I can open them up and view up without issue.

Pages that are linked to the index page DO get their pictures rendered. The webpages and the pictures are both in their own directories so I'm really not sure what could be going on. The tag is correct as well as the file name.

For example-
On my index page I have `<img src="pics/opslogo.jpg">` which should point to `http://[internal site]/html/Old_Ops_Website/pics/opslogo.jpg`, which it does according to the page source, but it doesn't render even though I know the picture is in there.

On a separate page I have `<img src="pics/connection.jpg">` which should point to `http://[internal site]/html/Old_Ops_Website/pics/connection.jpg`, which it does, and it DOES render correctly.

Interestingly enough the pictures that won't render when hitting the site from the network DO render correctly on the host machine itself.

Here are the paths, taken from "copy-shortcut", to the images from the non-working page and a working one, respectively-

```
http://[internal site]/html/Old_Ops_Website/pics/ops-logo.jpg

http://[internal site]/html/Old_Ops_Website/pics/connection.jpg
```

Given those pieces of information, I'm absolutely bewildered as to why this isn't working.

Not sure if it makes any difference but the actual root of the website is located in "`C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT`" while the page I'm working on is located in "`C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT\html\Old_Ops_Website`". Both directories have index files.

I tried changing the index file to "test.html" and hitting it via "`http://[internal site]/html/Old_Ops_Website/test.html`" with the same results.

Also tried "`<img src="./pics/opslogo.jpg"/>`", just in case, but no-go still.

**Next steps taken-**

Ok so I tried it with the images that I know for sure to be working on other pages and they show up on the index page as well. I still don't understand why the others won't show up since all the images are located in the exact same directory and when viewing the website from the host server all images render correctly. Next I tried to link the images that aren't working to one of the other pages and they don't work there either. I've triple checked and the images are definitely in the right directory and in the correct format and I can open them up and view them.

What could be causing these specific images to not render on any of my pages, yet they render perfectly from the host machine itself?

Edit, more details-

I went ahead and set the site up on my public dev server- [here](http://www.galaxyforge.net/dev/html/ROOT/html/Old_Ops_Website). As you can see here- [pics](http://www.galaxyforge.net/dev/html/ROOT/html/Old_Ops_Website/pics) the photos are in the correct directory, the HTML page is referencing the correct images, but nothing is coming up. FYI - I didn't create this site. This is about 10-15 years old which is why I'm hiding it on our current site as an easter egg for people to get a laugh at.

Comment: Is it normal that you write ops-logo.jpg and sometimes opslogo.jpg? Is that why you do not see the page? Can you check the 404 error, what is the path retrieved there? Sometimes a base path can break relative urls.

Comment: Where's your `pics/` path located relative to your document root?

Comment: are the index file and pics directory in the same level or folder?

Comment: @Salketer the image path taken from Chrome is `http://[internal site]/html/Old_Ops_Website/pics/opslogo.jpg`

I changed the name of the image from "op-losto.jpg" to "oplogo.jpg" just in case that was causing issues.

Comment: @IkoTikashi The whole path to the `pics/` directory is `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT\html\Old_Ops_Website\pics`.

Comment: @noob The images are located in `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT\html\Old_Ops_Website\pics` and the html pages are located in 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT\html\Old_Ops_Website'.

The root for the whole website is 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT'.

Comment: How about permissions? Do all images have the same permissions?

Comment: @noob Unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: oops sorry I read the url wrong. Try this img src="html/Old_Ops_Website/pics/opslogo.jpg"

Comment: @IkoTikashi They should, they're all in the same directory. Just to be sure I just redid all the permissions and gave all users full access just in case. Still no luck.

Comment: @noob Still no luck :(

Comment: did you try hard refresh clt+r ? on <img src="pics/opslogo.jpg"/>

Comment: @noob Tried a forced refresh using all the different code snippits provided. Still no luck. I've never heard of anything having this issue before, quite bizarre.

Comment: ok copy paste the link: http://[internal site]/html/Old_Ops_Website/pics/opslogo.jpg  in a new tab and see if you can see the image

Comment: @noob Still no luck, same 404 resource not found error.
Something interesting I noticed is that when I hit the webpage via the normal URL on the host machine, as opposed to using localhost, the images don't show up there like they do when using "localhost". Could that narrow the issue down at all?

Comment: ok did you put the image on the server at all??

Comment: @noob Yep, all images are on the server and all images are rendering fine with the exception of the ones on the index.html page.

Comment: so each and image has full permisions right

Comment: @noob Yeah, absolutely, I just double checked to make sure.

Comment: I went ahead and set the site up on my public dev server- http://galaxyforge.net/dev/html/ROOT/html/Old_Ops_Website/ . As you can see here- http://galaxyforge.net/dev/html/ROOT/html/Old_Ops_Website/pics/  the photos are in the correct directory, the HTML page is referencing the correct images, but nothing is coming up. FYI - I didn't create this site. This is about 10-15 years old which is why I'm hiding it on our current site as an easter egg for people to get a laugh at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't you realize your file name is wrong.

try:

```
<img src="pics/opslogo.JPG"/>
```

Comment: Wow. I didn't even consider that to be an issue since they showed up on the host machine just fine. You're absolutely right, that was indeed the issue. Now I can stop ripping my hair out. Thank you so much!!!!